# Getting child properties to render in Kendo Grid - undefined

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo Grid, and I am trying to render child objects, but they are coming up as 'undefined'.  The problem is that I have checked the JSON that is returning, and it is not undefined.  Here is a stripped down Version:

```
<table id="grid">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr class="k-alt">
        <td>#= RecordId #</td>
        <td>#= Person.Name #</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Everything renders fine, but 'Person.Name' is said to be undefined (I can show the javascript if you want).  If I look in FireBug though, 'Person.Name' is populated in the object.  What am I missing? Also, let me know if you want any more info on what I am doing - just trying to keep it simple to read.

Comment: Can you show the JSON data that is being used? Or better yet, change your rowTemplate to include: `# console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); #` and post the string printed to the console?

Comment: My mistake was that there is a collection of Persons... not just a single one.